# Sharepoint list item page comments

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 website with a list of items,
i want that on an item page (displayForm.aspx) the webiste users will be able to add comments (wordpress like) to the item, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think discussion board list may meet your requirements without doing any custom development.

Please see the article at url
http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/19/create-discussion-board-in-sharepoint-2013-complete-tutorial/

If you are interested in creating custom UI you may also consider creating custom action which may link to a separate comments page where you would pass id of the item.
Please see below url for more details on how to create custom actions.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473643(v=office.12).aspx

Another option is create your own page layout based on a custom content type the page layout may contain a custom web part which would store comments on custom list or custom database based on your requirements.

Please let me know if you need more help or knowledge on any of the above options?

Regards,

Hiren Gondhiya