# Document Upload to SharePoint with VB.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sharepoint

At my company we have an initiative that allows users to submit "Winning Ideas". There is a form to fill out, and the user can upload documents on the form. The ideas are voted on by other employees, reviewed by a committee, and the user has the ability to win cash prizes and have their idea implemented in the company.

I created a custom webpart using ASP.NET that allows users to insert a row into a SQL table, and add documents to a SharePoint document list. The list of documents they upload is added to a field in the SQL table, and displayed as hyperlinks on the .aspx page.

Here are some of the **issues** I have seen with the document upload:
 - Document is not uploaded at all.
 - Document is uploaded, but not checked in.
 - Document is uploaded and checked in, but not linked to a record (the field did not update in SQL).
 - If adding multiple documents, both documents are uploaded but the content of the first document is repeated for all documents.
 - Multiple entries are created with the Insert statement.

I can't figure out if this is a problem with my SQL or my VB. Is there a better way I should be doing this? Any help would be appreciated.

My current **environment** is as such:
 - SharePoint 2013
 - SQL Server 2012
 - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

```
Partial Public Class WinningIdeasFormUserControl
Inherits UserControl
Public conn As SqlConnection
Public strDatabase As String
Public MyUserInfo As SPUser
Public strFiles As String
Public IdeaId As String
Public uploads As HttpFileCollection

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    'reference to file collection that was sent by the browser request'
    uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files 

    Try
        conn = New SqlConnection(strDatabase)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        strFiles = ""

        'SQL command to insert results into the database'
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [WinningIdeas] (Title, Idea, Submitter, SPUserID) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@Title, @Idea, @Submitter, '" & MyUserInfo.ID & "')"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", txtTitle.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idea", txtIdea.InnerText)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Submitter", MyUserInfo.Name)

        'confirms that the database has been updated'
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()
        'set IdeaId to the output of the record that was just added (ID it was assigned in database)'
        IdeaId = reader(0).ToString
        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Connection = Nothing

        If uploads.Count > 1 Then
            Try
                'if the user uploaded documents, make sure we add them'
                uploadDocuments()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Span1.InnerHtml = "An error has occurred while trying to upload your document(s). Please contact WinnDESK@winnco.com for more information. " & ex.Message & "."
            End Try
        ElseIf (reader.RecordsAffected = 1) Then 'if a record has been successfully created'
            SendEmail()
            Response.Redirect("/Pages/Submitted.aspx?IdeaId=" & IdeaId)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'change the <span> to show the error message'
        Span1.InnerHtml = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub uploadDocuments()
    'upload files'
    For i As Integer = 0 To (uploads.Count - 1)
        Dim fileSize As Int64
        fileSize = uploads(i).ContentLength
        'get the file name from whichever file we are currently saving'
        Dim filName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads(i).FileName)
        'TODO: Size exception is bringing the user to an exception page. catch as my exception'
        'make sure there are no empty files, make sure file is less than 50MB'
        If (fileSize > 0 And fileSize < 52428800) Then
            Dim spfile As SPFile = SPContext.Current.Web.Files.Add("/Documents/User%20Uploads/" + IdeaId + "_" + filName, FileField.PostedFile.InputStream)
            spfile.CheckIn("Checked in by " & MyUserInfo.Name & " for Idea " & IdeaId, SPCheckinType.MajorCheckIn)
            spfile.Publish("Published by " & MyUserInfo.Name & " for Idea " & IdeaId)
            'separate files with a ";" in the database'
            strFiles = strFiles + IdeaId + "_" + filName + ";"
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Your file, " & filName & ", was not uploaded correctly due to its size.")
        End If
    Next

    Try
        conn = New SqlConnection(strDatabase)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE WinningIdeas SET Documents = @Documents WHERE ID = " & IdeaId

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Documents", strFiles)

        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Connection = Nothing

        Response.Redirect("/Pages/Submitted.aspx?IdeaId=" & IdeaId)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'change the <span> to show the error message'
        Span1.InnerHtml = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes there are definitely better ways of achieving this. The problem is with the current design. Instead of SQL server to store metadata related WinningIdeas, use SharePoint custom Lists, and modify list edit Form. Depending on scale of your requirements, you can even use a document library to store documents and link them on list forms - and of course with no server side code.

Comment: Is there a way to show subqueries in a SharePoint custom list? I have a few tables in SQL: 1 holds the ideas, 1 holds votes (like or dislike), and 1 holds comments. In the equivalent of the "list all" view, the total likes, dislikes, and comments are totaled and displayed. Along with them are two custom buttons: a thumbs-up and a thumbs-down to indicate what the viewer votes. If I can do all of this with just a SharePoint list, I will see if it will resolve my issue.

Comment: Enable rating and develop functionality to store comments as shown [here](https://sureshunakka87.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/likes-rating-and-comments-on-sharepoint-pages/)

Comment: That's great! I'll try this out...yesterday I was trying to figure out how to link multiple documents to a list item. I know there is an attachments column, and I know you can assign a unique ID to each record and link it to the document library, but I couldn't find an elegant solution to do so. As far as I could tell, one has create an idea and upload documents separately, and not all in one step. Do you have any ideas for that?

Comment: I found this article searching a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393927/sharepoint-list-item-page-comments
I will look into this and see if it meets my requirements.